# Main Hibernate Session Closing automatically

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session, lazy-initialization

I have a parent and child entities as below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT")
public class Parent implements Comparable<Parent>, Serializable, Cloneable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1584115734363172986L;

    public static final int NAME_LENGTH = 300;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "gen-seq")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "gen-seq", strategy = "native",
        parameters = {@Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "parent_id_seq")})
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @BatchSize(size = 50)
    @SortNatural
    private SortedSet<Child> child = new TreeSet<>();
}
```

Child entity as below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Child")
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Child implements Comparable<Object>, Serializable, Cloneable, Step<Child> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9091312680432977997L;

    public static final int NAME_LENGTH = 255;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "gen-seq")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "gen-seq", strategy = "native",
        parameters = {@Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "child_id_seq")})
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId", nullable = false)
    private Parent parent;
}
```

I have configured Spring and Hibernate to process database operations, and to process Parent I have the following method added in the serviceimpl class.

```
public void processParent(final Long parentId, String userEmail) throws Exception {
getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback<Set<Void>>() {
    public void doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException    {
        Parent parent = (Parent) session.get(Parent.class, parentId);           
        if (parent!=null && parent.getChild()!=null) {
            for (Child child: parent.getChild()) {

                // here the session is still Open when I call
                child.getParent();

                //But when I call this
                Parent p = getParent(child.getParent().getId());

                //now here the session got closed automatically, and now I cannot process the parent object

                }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

In the above method, I have the session is opened until I call child.getParent() but if I call the below method which has another session itself which is not null, after returning the below method, then the session in above method is becoming null automatically.

```
public Parent getParent(final Long id) throws Exception {
Parent actionPoint = (Parent) getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback<Parent>() {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
    * @see org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateCallback#doInHibernate(org.hibernate.Session)
    */
    public Parent doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException {
        Parent parent = (ActionPoint) session.get(Parent.class, id);

        //here also session is still open
        return parent;
    }
}}
```

Can anyone help me how to fix the main session should not be closed or become null. I know this is a configuration problem, but I don't know what should be configured.

Thanks in Advance, as I am trying to figure it out this issue for past 2 weeks.

Comment: Just introduce Spring TransactionManager and annotate your Service methods with `@Transactional` to avoid manual sessions/transactions handling. If you set propagate to REQUIRED the same transaction will be used.

Comment: If you are using JTA -  change the property in Hibernate.cfg “current_session_context_class” to “managed”

Comment: @PRATHAPS the issue has solved to some extent, now I am not getting no session exception, i.e. the session is open. But when I call other method   `Parent parent = (Parent) getHibernateTemplate().get(Parent.class, parentId);
  if(parent != null) {
   Hibernate.initialize(parent.getChildren()); 
  }
 }` I am getting no session error at Hibernate.initialize(parent.getChildren());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `@Transactional` above method and transaction will close at the end of the method. To enable `@Transactional` annotation you can add following code in your `context-persistence.xml`:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<!-- Session Factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <!-- <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/> -->
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.default_schema" value="${database.default_schema}" />
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}" />
            <entry key="show_sql" value="true" />
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="${hibernate.dialect}" />
            <entry key="transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks Man..it helped me to solve the issue with transaction.factory_class